# Comparing strings as list objects

Tags: python-2.7

I was working on python 2.7 on a program wherein python prints the longest word of a sentence. I split the words into a list using the string functions. Is it possible to compare these list objects without using any inbuilt functions?

For example
Input : a aa aaaa aaa
Output: aaaa

I'm a beginner so would be cool if someone could post some good tutorials I can resort to alongwith the answer

Comment: Your question is not very clear at the moment. You should provide some example input and expected output.

Comment: Made the edits. Added the expected input and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find the longest string in a list without using built-in functions? Try the following:

```
l = ["a", "aa", "aaaa", "aaa"]
longest = None
for x in l:
    if longest is None or len(x) > len(longest):
        longest = x
print(longest)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Was entirely confused how to compare list elements.

Answer (score 0):

Small and concise approach would be to get maximum value of elements in list according to elements length:

```
seq = ['a', 'aa', 'aaaa', 'aaa']
assert max(seq, key=len) == 'aaaa'
```